# PhD admissions: what to do when not shortlisted at top choice program?

Tags: phd, application, hong-kong

I applied for a PhD program at HKU and contacted a professor ahead of time. The professor said that it depends on the committee to decide the students. Then after one month, when I asked for my application status, the professor said that I am not in the shortlist for the main round. But I really like this program. What other efforts I can do at this time? For example, sending a love letter to the professor, or polishing my research proposal?

Comment: That was just a polite way of saying that you were not selected. At this point there is nothing you can do (definately do **not** sent love letters). Try again next year or find an alternative.

Comment: A philosopher once wrote: "you can't always get what you want".

Answer (score 5):

To convert Maarten's correct comment to an answer:

This is a polite way of saying that your application was not successful. It is very unlikely that you can change this. Time to move on: try elsewhere, try next year, or take a different path.

You could try politely asking for feedback to help you improve future applications. You may or may not receive anything.